# Spring Filter ClassCastException when running project on Tomcat

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, servlets, jackson

I am getting following error when I try to run my project on Tomcat. It was working before but I updgraded jackson version to 1.9.13 from 1.9.7 and I was not able to run the project anymore after updating maven dependencies. I tried to downgrade Jackson to 1.9.7 but no chance.

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter txTrackFilter
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Filter
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:275)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4001)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4651)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825)
at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:255)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Aug 3, 2014 12:11:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart
```

I have checked all answers related to this problem. They all say that I need to define scope as provided and I already have. Here is my servlet-api dependency definition.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I can't find any servlet-api dependency under any of dependency in my pom.xml. Here is all my pom.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.stg</groupId>
<artifactId>stg</artifactId>
<name>STG</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    <hibernate.version>4.1.6.Final</hibernate.version>
    <jackson.version>1.9.13</jackson.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Others -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
                <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is mvn dependency:tree of my project.

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.1.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.1.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.15.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.6:runtime (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.6:runtime
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15:runtime
[INFO] +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.7:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:7.0.52:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:7.0.52:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.5.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.7.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.13:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-infrastructure:jar:2.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |        \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:7.0.52:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:7.0.52:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:7.0.52:compile
[INFO]    \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO]       +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO]       \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I spent several hours on this problem but I got stuck. Even if I disable filtering, I am getting another class cast exception related to this servlet-api scope problem. But I can't find any servlet-api jar.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What container are you running on? And what version is it on?

Comment: Check your WEB-INF/lib of the war for any other jar contains ```javas.servlet.*``` classes.

Comment: Try `mvn dependency:tree` to list the full effective dependencies of your project. This will include transitive dependencies that you may have missed.

Comment: I tried mvn dependency:tree but nothing special. Added it to the question. I will check jars under WEB-INF/lib of the war one by one.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sorry, I can't understand your question? What is container? Tomcat?

Comment: It worked finally. Thank you all for your helpful comments :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got it working.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
                <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

There is tomcat package under these dependencies and servlet package in it. I only use them for com.fasterxml.jackson package. Shame on me. I removed these two everything is back to normal. Thanks Karthikeyan for suggestion to check maven dependency folders.